# How to block website for particular mac user on DSL-2730U

Tags: wireless-networking, modem, wifi-configuration

I have  DSL-2730U modem  I use windows 8.1 os and I have 4 smart phones and I want to block facebook.com for only 1 phone and other phone can still access facebook.com so how do i achieve this on my modem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the [manual](http://setuprouter.com/router/dlink/dsl-2730u/manual-1648.pdf) for your router you have the option for URL filtering however these rules appear to apply globally to all devices.

Alternatively, you can set IP Filtering rules which will allow you to block traffic based on source **and** destination IP/port. If you look at page 51 of the manual I linked to above you can see the steps required to setup an Outbound IP filtering rule. The caveat to this approach is that you will manually need to find which IP addresses Facebook uses in your area.